# c# Phantom constructor error

Tags: c#, constructor

I changed the constructor of an object but it always says that the constructor don't take 6 arguments or when I add a string in where a object was in the constructor it still thinks that its the old constructor.

```
Unit kaka = new Unit(
   new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 
   new Vector2(0), 
   0f, 
   0, 
   "Unit", 
   "Worker",
   player.GetPlayerNumber.ToString());
```

new constructor

```
public Unit(
   Rectangle newRectangle, 
   Vector2 newPosition, 
   float newFloor, 
   int textureRectangleBlock, 
   string newTextureType, 
   string newType, 
   string newPlayer)
   : base(newRectangle, 
          newPosition, 
          newFloor, 
          textureRectangleBlock, 
          newTextureType)
{
    unitClass = (Class)Enum.Parse(typeof(Class), newType);
    player = (Player.PlayerNumber)Enum.Parse(typeof(Player.PlayerNumber), newPlayer);
    stats = new Stats(100, 100, 10, 5, 5, 6, 0.5f, 1);
}
```

old constructor

```
public Unit(
   Rectangle newRectangle, 
   Vector2 newPosition, 
   float newFloor, 
   int textureRectangleBlock, 
   string newTextureType, 
   string newType, 
   Player newPlayer)
   : base(newRectangle, 
          newPosition, 
          newFloor, 
          textureRectangleBlock, 
          newTextureType)
{
    unitClass = (Class)Enum.Parse(typeof(Class), newType);
    player = newPlayer;
    stats = new Stats(100, 100, 10, 5, 5, 6, 0.5f, 1);
}
```

And here is the error :

```
Error   6   Argument 7: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Engine.Player'
   C:\Users\Pokemon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\
      Projects\BestGame\BestGame\BestGame\Game1.cs  93  
101 Voidless
```

And if I change to the old constructor the problem vanish, is the files bad or something please help.

Comment: Did you re-compile the code after changes been done? Is the class `Unit` present in different dll?

Comment: Do both old and new constructor exists? I mean you are probably using only the new one and commented/deleted the old one right?

Comment: Show us all the other constructors of this class and the base class

Comment: what is your type of `player` variable in the constructor method ?

Comment: What is the type of field "player" in your class? BTW nice user name ;)

Comment: The error is clear: the constructor is expecting a `Engine.Player` and you're passing a `string`. Somewhere in your code you're still calling the old constructor. @semao: I was thinking the same about the username `pokemon`.. :D

Comment: There are no old constructor I changed the old one to the new one, I found a way how to fix it but still... if I change the name of the Class Unit to Unit2 the problem fixed -_-...

Comment: I am not so sure what do you mean be re-compile @Rahul.

Comment: Thats the problem there is no old constructor @Abbas

Comment: The player is an Enum. @Turbot

Comment: Yes the Unit class is not in the main he is in Engine Class Library. @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess it really was some kind of Class ghost I moved copied and deleted the same Unit Class few time in different folders (Folders that the class could be), made few more constructors (at first I couldn't even use another constructor at all) and somehow the problem was solved I guess there was an old ghost class in one of those folders(didn't show at any search at all) and when I moved and deleted the class there, it deleted it for good, thank you for your help and suggestions, and sorry for bothering you for nothing.